# gerar consulta dinamicamente com union

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ';
$cola = ' UNION '; // Deixar os espaços em branco "em volta".
$colaWhere = ' WHERE ';
$first = true;

$wheres = "";



foreach($arrayNomeBDs as $nomeBD){
    $where = ' status = 2'. ' AND nomePessoa="O aqui vai variar" ';
    if($first == true){
        $wheres .= $sql . $nomeBD .$colaWhere . $where. $cola;
        $first = false;

    } else {
        $wheres .= $sql . $nomeBD .$colaWhere . $where. $cola;
    }
}
```

Ele está gerando assim:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab1 WHERE status = 2 AND nomePessoa="O aqui vai variar" UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab2 WHERE status = 2 AND nomePessoa="O aqui vai variar" UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab3 WHERE status = 2 AND nomePessoa="O aqui vai variar" UNION`

como eu removo o último union? que dica de implementação vocês poderiam me dar?
uma boa maneira é verificar o ultimo índice do array, se for eu não coloco o `UNION`? a mesma coisa se só tiver um nome do banco de dados na array, eu devo tirar o `UNION`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que colocar cada consulta montada em um array e, em seguida, utilizar a função `implode` seria também uma forma de unir suas consultas.

```
    $wheres[] = 'SELECT * FROM x';
    $wheres[] = 'SELECT * FROM y';
    $wheres[] = 'SELECT * FROM z';

    $wheres_compiled = implode(' UNION ', $wheres);

    var_dump($wheres_compiled); // SELECT * FROM x UNION SELECT * FROM y UNION SELECT * FROM z
```

## [Exemplo IDEONE](http://ideone.com/fLf8r8)

Imagino que, no seu caso, o resultado desejado seja algo como abaixo:

```
$tables = ['table_1', 'table_2', 'table_3'];

$wheres = [];

foreach ($tables as $table) {

    $wheres[] = sprintf('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE nomePessoa="%s"', $table, 'Aqui vai variar');
}

$compiled_with_unions = implode(' UNION ', $wheres);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim), além dessa existe a `ltrim()` e `trim()` que servem pra remover espaços (*se não especificado parâmetro)* ou um texto especificado no parâmetro. No caso do `rtrim` será apenas no lado **direito**, enquanto `ltrim` é apenas no lado esquerdo e `trim` ambos os lados. Exemplo:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab1 WHERE status = 2 AND nomePessoa="O aqui vai variar" UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab2 WHERE status = 2 AND nomePessoa="O aqui vai variar" UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab3 WHERE status = 2 AND nomePessoa="O aqui vai variar" UNION';
$sql = rtrim($sql, "UNION");
```

Saída:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab1 WHERE status = 2 AND nomePessoa="O aqui vai variar" UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab2 WHERE status = 2 AND nomePessoa="O aqui vai variar" UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab3 WHERE status = 2 AND nomePessoa="O aqui vai variar"

### [IdeOne Exemplo](http://ideone.com/dTe4xZ)